# Using KineticJS to remove drawn objects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

Hopefully a simple question here:

Say I've used KineticJS to draw a line as follows:

```
var redLine = new Kinetic.Line({
      points: [73, 70, 340, 23, 450, 60, 500, 20],
      stroke: "red",
      strokeWidth: 15,
      lineCap: "round",
      lineJoin: "round"
    });
```

And it's been added to a layer which has been added to the stage.

But now I need to completely remove this line as if it was never there to react to some user event. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

let's say you have a layer like below:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer(....);
```

to remove your `redLine` from the layer write:

```
layer.remove(redLine);
```

Comment: Shoot it's THAT easy? OK I think this is the library for me. Cheers mate

Comment: redLine.remove() removes redLine shape, layer.remove() remove the layer, regardless of how many arguments you give it...

Answer (score 10):

`container.remove()` removes **this** from it's parent container, while `container.removeChildren()` removes all the **children** from this container. Neither of them accepts any parameter.

remember to redraw the layer after you remove it.

Answer (score 5):

layer.remove() removes your layer... To remove a single shape, use shape.remove(), I can't find it documented anywhere... but apparently it works...

Answer (score 0):

My best solution was to use one simple method: shape.hide(); 
This methods hides the shape and this "removes" it from your drawing, you won't see it anymore, but I think the shape is still there, not completely sure.